# full screen background, single page website

Tags: html, css, background, fullscreen

I'm trying to build a very simple one page website. Here's a wireframe model: [image]

I have a very large background graphic (1920 x 1080) and I would like it to cover the whole page and when the browser window is made smaller, I would like scrollbars to appear (or something similar; the point is that the bg resizes). The page will also have some header text and a logo in the middle and a button below it and some text under a line after that.

I have tried:

```
html { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But if I make the browser window too small, it shows up wrong. I experimented having the top most and bottom most text IN the background graphic but after resizing to a very small size the sides of the text get cut off.

Another thing that almost works is this:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #f8f7e5 url('../images/background.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But the text won't play nice with that.

So my question would be, what would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: How small is 'too small'? and the text getting cut off has nothing to do with the background image look at `word-wrap` to solve that issue

Comment: Well I would like the website to look nice on desktop and mobiles.

Comment: 'Too small' still isn't a very accurate description that could be interpreted as 100px or 400px depending on the person.... To help us better understand I would suggest creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I can't give a specific pixel amount but the optimum situation would be that no matter what the size of the browser screen, the viewer would be able to view the site correctly. The latter code I listed is working ok'ish, the problem I have is that the text doesn't stay fixed with the background when the window is resized. I would like it to remain in its position and if the window is resized smaller than the text (width wise) then there would be a scroll bar. Does any of this make sense?

Comment: I would recommend using CSS gradients for a simple background like this. They'd scale down as well

Comment: Is the background y-repeatable like in your mockup? Is it required that the image will _fit_ horizontally or might a small amount of the left and right edges be cut off if the window is smaller than the image width?

Answer (score 1):

I would use background-size: cover for my background-image.  It is well supported except in IE8.  I would also set my background-image in media-queries so that I could have one or more smaller images for smaller size resolutions and use the larger image only on the largest devices.  This way a small mobile device doesn't need to download a giant 1920px x 1080px image.

Your media queries can also be used to set your text for different devices.  For example, you could have 3 divs for the text at the top of the screen that are each set to a width of 33.33333% and floated left so that they sit side-by-side on a desktop size screen.  On the smallest devices, such as a mobile phone that is in portrait mode though you could set each of those columns to be 100% so that they are one on top of each other.

It requires a little thoughtful planning before hand, but if you're having trouble, sit down with a pencil and a paper and make 3-5 mockups for how you want things to look at different screen sizes.  It could be as simply as one for a mobile device, one for a tablet device and another for a desktop device.  Build your css for the smallest device size and make that look reasonably good, then create a media query for the next largest category of screens and start adapting your css to fit those size devices, and then do the next.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I think you might be looking for. I used `background-size:100% 100%;` so it will distort your image when you resize your page if the image isn't large enough. But it does always cover the entire background. Hope this helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/JF9me/